# Maven private internal repository

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, artifactory

I have create a maven local depository using "Artifactory". I want to add project dependencies to this local repository(all dependencies in my local .m2 folder), can I do that with Artifactory?. If can, how can I do it?

Comment: Just do the correct configuration in settings.xml to use your artifactory and run your builds. They will automatically downloaded and put into Artifactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependencies will be added to Artifactory on the first run of your maven project (they will be fetched from one of the remote repositories Artifactory come preconfigured with).